# If condition joined query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, relationship

I have made a query in Laravel by joining 2 tables based on an IF condition.
I need to add a where query to filter data based on the material_id column from joined tables.

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
    ->select('transactions.id', DB::raw("IF(transactions.is_sell = '1', advertisements.material_id, offerrequests.material_id) as material_id"))
    ->leftJoin('advertisements', function ($join) {
        $join->on('advertisements.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('offerrequests', function ($join) {
        $join->on('offerrequests.id', '=', 'transactions.post_id');
    });
```

I have tried the following and it is querying data with the requesting material_id from joined tables.
but also in the end i can see transaction values which are not similar to 'material_id' in the input.
I need to only get data which is exactly matches the same material id.

```
$transactions = $transactions->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('advertisements.material_id', $request->material)
                    ->orWhere('offerrequests.material_id', $request->material);
                })->get();
```

Comment: can you replace `->orWhere(` with `->andWhere(` and test

Answer (score 0):

try below ...Instead of orwhere try andWhere

```
$transactions = $transactions->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('advertisements.material_id', $request->material)
                    ->andWhere('offerrequests.material_id', $request->material);
                })->get();
```

or

```
$transactions = $transactions ->where('advertisements.material_id', $request->material);
$transactions = $transactions ->where('offerrequests.material_id', $request->material);
$transactions = $transacions ->get();
```